# .htaccess configuration Redirect to index.php loses query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following configuration on my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

This should redirect the query to index.php and is doing that but is losing the Query String information.

For example if I request:

http://example.com/hello/user?name=stackoverflow

If I print the `$_REQUEST` variable or the `$_GET` variable I don't get any values. If I check `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING]` I don't have any value but on the `REQUEST_URI` I get: `/hello/user?name=stackoverflow`.

FYI: This is a LAMP Stack

I get the feeling that my `.htacccess` is incorrect, if I do: `http://example.com/hello/test.php?name=stackoverflow`

I can see the information of the query string (on the `$_SERVER`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET`).

Any ideas on why the .htaccess configuration is wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Are you sure the request is redirecting to `index.php`? How **exactly** are you _"printing"_ the `$_REQUEST` / `$_GET` variable?

Comment: I'm positive that I'm redirecting to index.php since everything is working as it should but the GET variables are not being received. I have tested this script locally and it's working as it should. The $_REQUEST or $_GET are printed using var_dump

Comment: Everything seems fine. I copied your rewrite rules exactly and they work as expected. Might be a long shot but try adding `Options -MultiViews`